# Is there a DRYer XPath expression for union?

Tags: xpath, union, expression, dry

This works nicely for finding button-like HTML elements, (purposely simplified):

```
  //button[text()='Buy']
| //input[@type='submit' and @value='Buy']
| //a/img[@title='Buy']
```

Now I need to constrain this to a context. For example, the Buy button that appears inside a labeled box:

```
//legend[text()='Flubber']
```

And this works, (.. gets us to the containing fieldset):

```
  //legend[text()='Flubber']/..//button[text()='Buy']
| //legend[text()='Flubber']/..//input[@type='submit' and @value='Buy']
| //legend[text()='Flubber']/..//a/img[@title='Buy']
```

But is there any way to simplify this? Sadly, this sort of thing doesn't work:

```
//legend[text()='Flubber']/..//(
  button[text()='Buy']
| input[@type='submit' and @value='Buy']
| a/img[@title='Buy'])
```

(Note that this is for XPath within the browser, so XSLT solutions will not help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From comments:**

> Adjusting slightly to obtain the A
>   rather than the IMG:
>   `self::a[img[@title='Buy']]`. (Now if
>   only 'Buy' could be reduced

Use this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//legend[text() = 'Flubber']/..
   //*[
      self::button/text()
    | self::input[@type = 'submit']/@value
    | self::a/img/@title
    = 'Buy'
   ]
```

**EDIT**: I didn't see the parent accessor. Other way in one direction only:

```
//*[legend[text() = 'Flubber']]
   //*[
      self::button/text()
    | self::input[@type = 'submit']/@value
    | self::a/img/@title
    = 'Buy'
   ]
```

Comment: Hmm, this compares the concatenation of the 3 values, which should work in this simplified example with mutually exclusive parts. Interesting how my original problem is heavy-handed use of the union operator, and this refinement is subtle use of union.

Comment: @Chris Noe: This use node set comparison (not "concatenation") and those relative paths inside the last predicate are mutually exclusive by themself because they all start with the self axis: they will work with any document whether simple or complex.

Comment: Yep, this opens up some new horizons. Thx!

Comment: Sadly this does not seem to work: normalize-space(@value|@title|@alt)='Buy', although this does: starts-with(@value|@title|@alt, 'Buy')

Comment: @Chris Noe: XPath 1.0 functions have implicit casting, thus node sets become singleton (first node) and then are casted with `number()`, `string()` or `boolean()`. But those relative path are exclusive, so there should be no problem. Alternativily, you could use for not exclusive expressions: `boolean((@value|@title|@alt)[normalize-space()='Buy'])` or `boolean((@value|@title|@alt)[starts-with()='Buy'])`. With conditional instructions there is no need for starting `boolean()`.

Comment: Looks like the starts-with example needs to be: boolean((@value|@alt)[starts-with(.,'Buy')]), and can be shortened to (@value|@alt)[starts-with(.,'Buy')]

Comment: @Chris Noe: Indeed. It was a crappy copy&paste

Answer (score 3):

Combine multiple conditions in a single predicate:

```
//legend[text()='Flubber']/..//*[self::button[text()='Buy'] or 
                                 self::input[@type='submit' and @value='Buy'] or
                                 self::img[@title='Buy'][parent::a]]
```

In English:

> Select all descendants of the parent (or the parent itself)
>   for any `legend` element having the
>   text "Flubber" that are any of 1) a `button`
>   element having the text "Buy" or 2) an
>   `input` element having an attribute
>   `type` whose value is "submit" and an
>   attribute named `value` whose value is
>   "Buy" or 3) an `img` having an
>   attribute named `title` with a value
>   of "Buy" and whose parent is an `a`
>   element.

Comment: Very nice. Adjusting slightly to obtain the A rather than the IMG: self::a[img[@title='Buy']]. (Now if only 'Buy' could be reduced :)